# How to execute code after "deferred" script is loaded and executed?

Tags: javascript, deferred

If scripts are loaded synchronously (incl. jQuery), then startup code I use is the following:

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function () {
        // some startup code
    });
</script>
```

Now scripts are *deferred*:

```
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="...
```

How do I rewrite my startup code so it executes **after** deferred scripts are loaded and processed?

Answer (score 5):

The approach I've used is to listen to the 'load' event of that specific script tag - once it's done and good to go, the event will fire.

```js
theScript.addEventListener('load', function () {
    console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery);
});
```

```html
<script defer id='theScript' type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this of course is easier by simply adding an onload to the tag

```
<script defer src="foo.js" onload="callback()"></script>
```

Your callback can trigger an event. Theoretically you can use the DOMContentLoaded event but I've had some trouble with js not being fully available when this fires